# Desktop PC won't turn off the display automatically?

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop

I set the power plan to both **Balanced** and **High Performance** and set the time to turn off display to 1 minute. However, no matter how long I wait, the display just won't turn off,let alone entering sleep mode. I have left all the Homegroup and even prevented every devices from waking up the PC (such as mouse, keyboard).  The apps I have installed and run in the background are: **Kaspersky, NVIDIA Geforce Experience Ceter,  Tuneup Utility, Realtek HD Audio Manager, Rainmeter, Dropbox.** Please help me figure out where the problem lies. I don't form a habit of turning off PC when I leave and I don't want my display to burn out. Thanks!

Comment: forgot to mention, the OS is Windows 8.1. I've installed all the updates.

Comment: In very rare cases, it will turn off the display normally, however I did nothing for this to happen. And the problem arises again when next boot-up.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is with OneDrive, I never use it and don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: Did you change the power plan settings form TuneUp Utilities?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same issue and have fixed it.

For me the problem was due to my Microsoft Keyboard (http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-ergonomic-desktop#support). The solution is to simply install the keyboard and mouse drivers from Microsoft.

I found the solution here: http://forums.cnet.com/7726-7590_102-2767704.html

I have my power plan set to performance and screen

Answer (score 0):

If you leave Windows Media Player open, it can prevent the screen saver from activating (handy if you're watching a movie with it).  You can go into its settings and enable "Allow screen saver during playback."